# Mule Domain Project Dependency Failed using maven

Tags: maven, mule, maven-plugin, mulesoft

I have a mule domain project created and the mule runtime is on-premise stand alone server. I deployed the domain project manually to the server and working fine.

Created another project, and referred domain as a dependency but the mvn clean package is throwing error , how to resolve that ?

here is the pom looks like for that

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>1234-1234-1234-b5be-276954c67e1e</groupId>
        <artifactId>erie</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-domain</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and i get below error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for c6811e03-978c-4711-b5be-276954c67e1e:cir:jar:mule-domain:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1321814, ConflictMarker.markTime=464641, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=469, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=226134, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=776107, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=197, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=23849407, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=398, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=1095978322, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=26653889}
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cir-sys-sfdc: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:cir-sys-sfdc:mule-application:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find c6811e03-978c-4711-b5be-276954c67e1e:cir:jar:mule-domain:1.0.0 in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1] 2020-07-08T19:03:33.7624649Z org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project cir-sys-sfdc: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:cir-sys-sfdc:mule-application:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find c6811e03-978c-4711-b5be-276954c67e1e:cir:jar:mule-domain:1.0.0 in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced 2020-07-
```

How do i resolve that and the maven build is looking for the domain jar in anypoint exchange , does i meant that i should publish domain project to exchange and what if its environmental specific ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the domain project (`mvn deploy`) before trying to use it? You have to follow the instructions at https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-publish-assets-maven#publish-an-asset-to-exchange-using-maven

I don't think Anypoint Exchange supports specifically domain projects, so I'm not sure how it will go if you publish it.

Comment: i guess that works for normal application. But for domain project no where mentioned what are the steps to follow .

Comment: Please share the complete error message from Maven. May the rest of the error gives more insight.

Comment: added the image to the question.

Comment: Did you perform the deploy of the domain?

Comment: yes the domain project is deployed on the server manually. and from TFS server when i try to deploy a new app which is dependent on domain project, its throwing the above error